# Finding Volume of Cube from Co-Ordinate Points

Tags: geometry

If I am given two 3-D points of a cube,how do I find the volume of that Cube?where $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ is the co-ordinate of one corner and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ is the co-ordinate of the opposite corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute first the diagonal length $d=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}$. An edge of the cube has length $s=d/\sqrt3$ and $V=s^3=d^3/(3\sqrt3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are opposite corners then the length $a$ is $a = \vert x_1 - x_2 \vert = \vert y_1 - y_2 \vert  =\vert z_1 - z_2 \vert$, and thus $V = a^3$.